# How does vt aware applications such as vscode terminal know of changes in console when those changes are implemented through win32 api calls?

Tags: visual-studio-code, winapi, pty

In Windows, a new PseudoConsole is created via CreatePseudoConsole().
The server can then read any inputs received from a client by reading the pseudoconsole handle and can write inputs to it.

This is all fine, but the complexity arises when we need mode changes. For most platforms, this is done through virtual terminal sequences, but with Windows it was implemented by win32 calls.

So newer, vt aware applications have no problems with pty's but what about legacy applications that used these win32 calls to implement mode changes?

Now I expected them to break when run on a pty, but they didn't. So I made a simple app that changes the cursor information of the console to test it out.

```
int  wmain(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    HANDLE hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO curInfo;
    if(!GetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &curInfo))
        return false;
    
    
    std::cout << "Size:" << curInfo.dwSize << " " << "Visibility:" << curInfo.bVisible << "\n";

    curInfo.dwSize = 20; curInfo.bVisible = false;
    if(!SetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &curInfo))
    {
        std::cout << "Setting info failed\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "How's new cursor\n";

    if(!GetConsoleCursorInfo(hOut, &curInfo))
        return false;

    std::cout << "Size:" << curInfo.dwSize << " " << "Visibility:" << curInfo.bVisible << "\n";

    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    return true;
```

This program was run in both windows terminal and vscode integrated terminal.
I initially thought that the SetCursorInfo function will succeed inorder to remain compatible with a legacy application but not actually do anything. To my surprise, not only did SetCursorInfo() succeed, it also managed to make the cursor invisible.

My question is how is this possible if the server application is only reading the pseudoconsole input handle. Is it
a) The server app has a dedicated thread that constantly calls GetCursorInfo() and other such property changing functions to monitor changes in the console and then apply them?
b) The windows pseudoconsole engine converts the win32 call to vt sequence and posts that into the pseudoconsole read pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Console [Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-visibility).

> The DECTCEM sequences are generally equivalent to calling
> [SetConsoleCursorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorinfo) console API to toggle cursor visibility if
> the ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING flag is set on the screen
> buffer handle using the [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) function.

And For Created Pseudo Console, [The input and output streams encoded as UTF-8 contain plain text interleaved with Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createpseudoconsole#remarks).